expo modules (expo-constants) not working when newArchEnabled set to true
I have a fresh initialized react-native app (npx react-native@latest - 0.75.1). I'm adding expo-modules (npx install-expo-modules@latest - 51.0.0). For testing I added expo-device, and expo-constants.
On iOS (RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1) every thing works fine (fabric is set to true).
On Android (newArchEnabled=true) build works fine but I'm getting an error:
*Invariant Violation: "rnQRScan" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called.*


When I'm setting newArchEnabled to false (gradle.porperties), build works fine and the app works as expected.
Any idea?
